# Twitter Bootsrap 3 modal not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page that has two potential modals to display. One (and this one works) is only displayed after the user performs a certain function. The other, will prompt the user and ask if they want to delete a position.

Here is a fiddle that I have setup:

[Fiddle of non working modal](https://jsfiddle.net/mwoods98/962dfxbo/6/)

Code:

```
                        <div class="pull-centered">
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" data-target="#Delete"  ID="DeletePosButton" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Delete Position</a> 
                         </div>
<!-- This is the modal that doesn't work -->

            </form> 
                 <script>
                      $('#EditPosition').submit(function(){
                          $('#SavePosition').val('Updating...');
                          $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                      });
                </script>           


<!-- modal window content, the id of the containing div must match the href on the toggle button -->
<div class="modal fade" id="RemoveCandidate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hedden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
          <h3 id="modalLabel"><cfoutput>Remove the current assignment?</cfoutput></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <div class="well">
            <cfoutput>
             <form action="#event.buildlink(rc.RemoveTourAssignment)#" id="dropposition" method="post">
                <input id="pos_id" type="hidden" name="pos_id" value="#rc.pos_id#">
                <input id="ThetourID" type="hidden" name="ThetourID" value="0"> 
              </cfoutput>
                <fieldset>
                  Click anywhere outside of this window to cancel.
                  <div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="submit" id="removethisposition" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove Assignment">
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form> 

                 <script>
                      $('#removeassignment').submit(function(){
                          $('#removethisposition').val('Removing...');
                          $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                      });
                </script>              
          </div> <!-- end of well -->
      </div>
  </div>


    <!-- modal window content, the id of the containing div must match the href on the toggle button -->
<div class="modal fade" id="Delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hedden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
          <h3 id="modalLabel">Delete position IP:a103 ?</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <div class="well">

              <form action="" id="dropposition" method="post">
                <input id="pos_id" type="hidden" name="pos_id" value="1605">
                <input id="ftfIPNumber" type="hidden" name="ftfIPNumber" value="a103">

                <fieldset>
                  Click anywhere outside of this window to cancel.
                  <div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="submit" id="deletethisposition" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete Position">
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form> 
               <script>
                    $('#dropposition').submit(function(){
                        $('#deletethisposition').val('Deleting...');
                        $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    });
                </script> 
          </div> <!-- end of well -->
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

<!-- This is the code that activates the modals I do have a page that has two separate modals that work on the same page together however, unless I remove id="RemoveCandidate" id="Delete" will not work -->
```

This is the code that activates the modals I do have a page that has two separate modals that work on the same page together however, unless I remove id="RemoveCandidate" id="Delete" will not work

Also excuse the #'s around some variables. It's written in ColdFusion

Answer (score 0):

1) You have aria-hedden instead of aria-hidden

2) You aren't closing your div, form, and fieldset tags correctly

3) You don't have a button set to open the RemoveCandidate at all

Try this:

```html
<div class="col-xs-9"align="left">
  <h3>Edit Position</h3>
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <div class="tabbable">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">Details</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="pane1" class="tab-pane active">
                        <div class="well"> 
                            <fieldset> 
                                <label class="control-label" for="SN">S/N:                 </label>
                                <div class="controls"><input id="SN" type="text" value="1605" class="form-control input-md" name="SN" disabled /></div>
                                <div class="pull-right"><input type="submit" id="SavePosition"  class="btn btn-success" value="Update Position" /></div>
                                <div class="pull-centered">
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger" data-target="#Delete"  ID="DeletePosButton" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Delete Position</a> 
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div><!-- /.well -->
                    </div> <!-- panel -->
                </div><!-- tab -->
            </div><!-- tabable -->
        </div><!-- col -->
    </div><!-- row -->
<!-- modal window content, the id of the containing div must match the href on the toggle button -->
<div class="modal" id="RemoveCandidate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
          <h3 id="modalLabel"><cfoutput>Remove the current assignment?</cfoutput></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <div class="well">
               <form action="#event.buildlink(rc.RemoveTourAssignment)#" id="dropposition" method="post">
                 <cfoutput>
                     <input id="pos_id" type="hidden" name="pos_id" value="#rc.pos_id#" />
                     <input id="ThetourID" type="hidden" name="ThetourID" value="0" /> 
                  </cfoutput>
                <fieldset>
                  Click anywhere outside of this window to cancel.
                  <div class="pull-right">
                      <input type="submit" id="removethisposition" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove Assignment" />
                  </div>
                   </fieldset>
               </form>
            </div> <!-- end of well -->
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>


    <!-- modal window content, the id of the containing div must match the href on the toggle button -->
<div class="modal fade" id="Delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
                <h3 id="modalLabel">Delete position IP:a103 ?</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="well">
                    <form action="" id="dropposition" method="post">
                        <input id="pos_id" type="hidden" name="pos_id" value="1605" />
                        <input id="ftfIPNumber" type="hidden" name="ftfIPNumber" value="a103" />
                        <fieldset>
                            Click anywhere outside of this window to cancel.
                              <div class="pull-right">
                                  <input type="submit" id="deletethisposition" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete Position" />
                              </div>
                           </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div> <!-- end of well -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I didn't change anything regarding RemoveCandidate but the Delete button should work if you use this HTML in your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Still having trouble and you're right I didn't include the RemoveCandidate in the code snip as the Delete was the problem child. It still is I'm going to come back to this post and to this issue to see if I can figure out what the issue is. Thanks for the reply and great catch on the misspelled hidden. I'll get back to this.